# Drywall hole, plaster, Primer and Paint

Tags: painting

I removed the toilet paper dispenser on the wall, covered up with compound, and sanded. I applied primer on the affected area but I painted the entire wall. So, now my wall is not consistent. Can I fix the problem by applying a few extra coats of paint in the area where I applied primer? If not, what is the best way to fix the problem?

Thanks so much!  [image][image]

Comment: Most likely a little extra paint will do it. But a picture would help.

Comment: What paint did you use?  Was it the exact same paint the wall was painted with? A computer color match?

Answer (score 1):

If the paint color is both:

- similar to (or the same as, but similar would do) the previous paint color and
- significantly **different, especially darker than,** the (probably white/off-white) primer color

then the newly primed area will not show the paint color as "completely" and an extra coat or two in that area should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I used Sherwin Williams Opulence Eg-shel. I am painting the entire wall and using the exact same color. 
Let me try to apply a few more coats of paint on the newly primed area.

Comment: FYI - the problem was fixed after 4 thick consistent coats of paint.

Comment: Seeing the picture, that does match my answer "different, especially darker than the primer color".

Comment: @DIYNewbie please up vote this answer if it helped you and either accept it, or post your comment as an answer an accept that. It helps to know that this question has a satisfactory answer.